# Why do my scroll bar & cursor move on their own?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, touchpad, cursor

I have a less than 3-year-old Dell Studio laptop running Windows 7, Internet Explorer 9. I use the touch pad, not a mouse. Lately the scroll bar moves on its own and the cursor does, too. The cursor bounces all over the place. This is driving me crazy! "I've read some of the answers to this question but I either don't understand what they're talking about or my computer doesn't have the "category" they say to click on.

Comment: Have you tried upating the driver for the touchpad? This can be found on the Dell support page http://support.dell.com/

Comment: It sounds like it could be a failing mouse connected to the USB port. Some laser mice wiggle around if they got confused about what they see (which happens at a certain distance from the surface), but they don't scroll around (unless the scroll wheel is not a mechanical wheel either).

Answer (score 1):

I've found before that wireless interference from another wireless input device can be a cause of similar problems. Maybe you could look for other wireless input devices in range?

Answer (score 0):

For weeks the problem was tabs multiplyed exponentially. Then the cursor raced to the end so I couldnt type any thing and the scroll bar plunged to the bottom. It was nuts.  I tried everything including replacing Win10. Nothing worked until I replace the driver on the keyboard. As soon as the new driver loaded, problems disappeared.